# Send a POST request with some data, including a file, using Curl

Tags: file, post, curl

How can I include a file in a curl request form my working directory?

Below I've got a POST request that includes data for "first_name" and for "last_name", but now I need to add in the input for file. Theres examples out there where someone is ONLY sending a file along, but I'm trying to send 1 or more files, and other data.

```
curl 
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
  -d '{ first_name: "Donny", last_name: "P", my_file: ???? }'
  https://sender.blockspring.com/api/blocks/319bfef4aad7f3477745048a2da3ae6a?api_key=2e0ef0c216078d60630d1321e67b243a
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be only done with a multipart.

Manually building a multipart may be complex, so curl has a built-in -F option.

```
curl localhost:8000 -F "my_file=@file.ext" -F "name=daniel;last=P" -v
```

from man curl

> -F, --form 
>                 (HTTP)  This  lets  curl emulate a filled-in form in which a user has pressed the submit button. This causes curl to POST
>                 data using the Content-Type multipart/form-data according to RFC 2388. This enables uploading of  binary  files  etc. 
>   To
>                 force  the  'content'  part  to be a file, prefix the file name with an @ sign. To just get the content part from a file,
>                 prefix the file name with the symbol <. The difference between @ and < is then that @ makes a file get  attached  in  the
>                 post as a file upload, while the < makes a text field and just get the contents for that text field from a file.